How to move object to right infront of the viewport camera
I have an Object and I rotate it -90 degrees and it flies away. I tried setting to local coordinates rotation and nothing helped I tried every single rotation option. So now I just want to move the object to the camera. Not camera like in an object camera but where I am right now. I just want the object to teleport into view. But not move me to the object!.
Iv'e tried looking online for any help on this issue and no one seems to know. Iv'e also tried every single combination of the shift+s options. I just want the object to move to me. Its gone somewhere and I want it back.

hello, you say that you rotate it -90 degrees and it flies away, could you please give more details or show a screenshot because it is not very clear what you are trying to do. You can't automatically move an object in front of the view, you can bring it back to the center of the scene with alt G though

Have to agree with @moonboots here, it is not clear what you are doing and what you want to do. For the object "flying off" I can only speculate (now I want speculoo) that it's not the coordinates that make the problem - global and and local coordinates might only be different on what axes the object rotates - but the Transform Pivot Point or the object's origin. For example, if the pivot point is set to 3D Cursor and the object is way off center. Or with the default Median Point, but the mesh and origin are way apart from each other.

I also suspect the origin to be far from the mesh, in that case right click in Object mode > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry
